# Fill voids in a butcher block

Tags: adhesive

I was commissioned to create a butcher block table and cutting board from poplar, walnut, cherry and ash.  Despite best efforts, both pieces have some voids which the Titebond III didn't fill. I am thinking of filling the smaller cracks with hide glue and the larger voids with a mix of hide glue and wood dust.  Ideas or suggestions?
Thanks.
I used 1.5" roughsawn for the ash, cherry and walnut, and planed random pieces, glued up strips... all to recreate an end grain butcher block table which I didn't really expect to be used as a butcher block.  I don't know that the glue-up at this point would be deemed unsafe for food contact, but the voids certainly have to be filled.  Had I known it would be used as a cutting block, I would probably have insisted on hard maple.

Comment: Is this a end grain butcher block table as used in old school butcher shops? Will the surface be used for food prep?

Comment: This would be an excellent question for the woodworking SE

Answer (score 4):

If you can, I would recommend cutting down the joint with a thin bandsaw blade & then machining *both pieces* with a jointer to get the super tight fit that you really should have between your boards.  The reason I suggest this is that cutting boards can give up particles when sliced/chopped on that would end up on the food that is processed on the cutting board (especially meat)--which I doubt you or anyone else would want to eat, due to the toxicity of adhesives.

If, on the other hand, you can find a non-toxic bonding adhesive then the above suggestion could be avoided.

hth
best regards!

Comment: This would be especially true for the cutting board which may see some wet service, that can break down the adhesive over time unless it's 'waterproof'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.  I would mix glue and sawdust until a got the consistency I wanted and use that as filler.